# Youtube iframe video play/mute in single button. Also toggle images when clicked play/mute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a single button for play/mute process for youtube iframe... I found some code from stack, which have 2 buttons for both actions. But I need only one button and when clicked the image of sound button should toggle to mute button and the video should be muted. Please help me for solving this out.
This is my code :

```
<iframe id="youtube_player" width="0" height="0" src="https://youtube.com/embed/dT6Z4_lxx7Q?enablejsapi=1;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=dT6Z4_lxx7Q" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<a id="play" href="#"><img src="sound.png" width="60px" height="60px"></a>
<a id="mute" href="#"><img src="mute.png" width="60px" height="60px"></a>
```

Comment: Code is missing...

Comment: Sorry @ristapk had some errors in posting code....Fixed it!! Please help to clear this problem...

Comment: @ArunCyber so when you play you want it to play with no sound? yes?

Comment: @ArunCyber i'm not sure why you would run that video muted - why not just have a black background? it's ALL music? http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/tyktk77L/

Comment: @RachelGallen - I just need the music to be played....I am using 2 iframes in this site one for video(no audio) and one for music...when website is taken, music starts autoplay thus, if pressed mute only music need to be muted and when pressed again it should be played. And the button images should also have a toggle effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is it, sorry for waiting...

CODEPEN link: http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/bZjJzQ

HTML:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="pauseplay">PAUSE</div>
```

CSS:

```
#player{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#pauseplay{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: cyan;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

JS:

```
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      //setTimeout(pauseVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function pauseVideo() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  }

function playVideo() {
    player.playVideo();
  }


  $('#pauseplay').on('click', function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('paused') ){
      $(this).removeClass('paused');
      $(this).text('PAUSE');
      playVideo();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('paused');
      $(this).text('PLAY');
      pauseVideo();
    }

  });
```

Comment: Thanks @ristapk this is the code i was looking for but can you just make a small change....other than the coloured div's with play/pause control, i need images for pause and play , which toggles according to the play/pause clicked.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Great, pleasure is all mine. :)